# Excel - Best Way To Perform Lookup In This Case?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a dataset (See attached)

[image]

However, I would like the Date Posted In Transpose Format, So I used transpose and pasted into another sheet. (See attached) But how do I populate the data for FB and TWTR respectively?

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with a pivot table?

Comment: @JSmart523 would need this file saved as csv for an import

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pivot: Excel Formula

[image]

**Sum**

- If you want to sum up the Hi column, then you can use the following formula:

[image]

```vb
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$25,(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$25=C$1)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$25=$A2)),"")
```

**Match**

- If you want to find the first occurrence i.e. there is only one Date/Symbol combination or the Hi column contains text, then you can use the following **array** formula:

[image]

```vb
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$25,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$25=C$1)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$25=$A2),0)),"")
```

Comment: the second formula works great but also looks intimidating. impressive writing it out tbh!

Comment: @VoidS some would create that by crafting each individual element and building up, others would just write it from left to right as a complete entity - comes with practice.